# Running Phantomjs using C# to grab snapshot of webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, phantomjs

I'm trying to grab snapshots of my own website using phantomjs - basically, this is to create a "preview image" of user-submitted content.

I've installed phantomjs on the server and have confirmed that running it from the command line against the appropriate pages works fine. However, when I try running it from the website, it does not appear to do anything. I have confirmed that the code is being called, that phantom is actually running (I've monitored the processes, and can see it appear in the process list when I call it) - however, no image is being generated.

I'm not sure where I should be looking to figure out why it won't create the images - any suggestions? The relevant code block is below:

```
string arguments = "/c rasterize.js http://www.mysite.com/viewcontent.aspx?id=123";
string imagefilename = @"C:\inetpub\vhosts\mysite.com\httpdocs\Uploads\img123.png";

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\phantomjs.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments + " " + imagefilename;

p.Start();
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Have you checked out what `output` actually is? There is good chance that when it starts it does not have enough privilegies to save to location you want... Consider dumping current user account from Phantom's script (not sure how to do it) or see what account it endup running under.

Comment: It's running as the .NET general account - same as when a user tries to upload an image (and I'm saving the generated image to the same directory, so it should have write-access to that directory).

Comment: Start with something simple first, e.g. PhantomJS script to display "Hello world". See if it outputs the message properly or not.

Comment: If running a simple script takes ages, you may be impacted by the proxy problem on Windows (see http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/issues/detail?id=580). Try to add `--proxy-type=none` command line argument to bypass the proxy server.

Comment: thanks. Ended up using a different scraping system, which also takes a while, but was able to debug better - it was some sort of file-access error, but phantomjs wasn't giving me enough information.

Comment: Elie may I ask what you used for scraping? Thanks.

Comment: There's a C# program I found online that uses the built in browser. I don't recall what program it is, but I found tips for working with it here on SO....

Answer (score 9):

I check the errors that phantomjs throws during its process.
You can read them from Process.StandardError.

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
//some other parameters here
...
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = startInfo;
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit(timeToExit);
//Read the Error:
string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

It will give you an idea of what happened

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way for executing phantomjs from C# code is using wrapper like [NReco.PhantomJS](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NReco.PhantomJS/). The following example illustrates how to use it for rasterize.js:

```
var phantomJS = new PhantomJS();
phantomJS.Run( "rasterize.js", new[] { "https://www.google.com", outFile} );
```

Wrapper API has events for stdout and stderr; also it can provide input from C# Stream and read stdout result into C# stream.

Comment: For those who use this method, the link to rasterize.js : https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js