# Htmlagilitypack after login

Tags: c#, facebook, httprequest, html-agility-pack

I want to parse some html site like facebook, 
Forexample `(www.facebook.com/somePage)`

If I want to paste this link to my explorer, it redirects me to login my account first. So I aint see that page. So I cant use Htmlagilitypack to get response.

So How can I first login site programmaticaly (without using webbrowser control) then call that facebook page and get response and parse with Htmlagility pack. I know How can I use HtmlAgility pack and I know setting cookies with Httprequest I Use following code to set cookies but after that how can I parse that **somePage**

```
CookieCollection cookies = new CookieCollection();
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.facebook.com");
            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            request.CookieContainer.Add(cookies);
            //Get the response from the server and save the cookies from the first request..
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            cookies = response.Cookies;
            response.Close();
        }
        catch (WebException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error");
        }

        string getUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1";
        string postData = String.Format("email={0}&pass={1}", "xxxx@hotmail.com", "xxxxx");
        HttpWebRequest getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(getUrl);
        getRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        getRequest.CookieContainer.Add(cookies); //recover cookies First request
        getRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
        getRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
        getRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
        getRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
        getRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        getRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
        getRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream newStream = getRequest.GetRequestStream(); //open connection
        newStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); // Send the data.
        newStream.Close();
        //How I parse (www.facebook.com/somePage) here?
       HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
       HttpWebResponse getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();
       using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251")))
        {

            doc.LoadHtml(sr.ReadToEnd());

        }

        foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(link.InnerHtml);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `HttpWebRequest` call the [`GetResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. This yields a `WebResponse` object on which you can call `GetResponseStream()` to get to the contents.

Since Facebook returns almost no HTML content (they send a load of Javascript for the browser to generate the Document from), the HtmlAgilityPack won't really help you. It will download the Javascript, but can't execute it, so you're stuck with a document that's hard to interpret.

Other Html packages, like [Awesonium](http://www.awesomium.com/) or [PhantomJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048895/running-phantomjs-using-c-sharp-to-grab-snapshot-of-webpage) can actually execute the Javascript and return you the interpreted HtmlDomDocument. These won't require you to run the whole browser, they can both run Headless (as it's called to run a browser without a UI on top of it).

Alternatively, use the [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/) to access the data on facebook without parsing the HTML, it's much stabler and built for the exact purpose of interacting with data on facebook.

Comment: Sir, I edited question, I did same but its not working